# Nodejs/javascript how to create modular front-end based on region

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node-modules

I'm trying to design a front-end system that displays a single html page with different widgets in it. Each widget occupies a different region in the page. Furthermore each widget should be completely modular, e.g. could be programmed by a different party. Also, each module is responsible for whatever backend it needs.

But dependencies are allowed. For example, a module could specify which other modules it need. Is this possible in Javascript? Or do I need to program this manually? Is one of the main front-end frameworks (Angular/React/Vue) capable of handling this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you're looking for is a front end framework where you render components on the server and deliver them to the client side.

You can do this with any modern front-end framework, but if you are new I would recommend learning Vue and Nuxt, since Vue is super easy to learn:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

You'll have to figure out the backend (i would suggest node atm since it really takes 10 minutes to set up max), and the express framework for handling routing, routing being 'am I trying to make a post vs get request from stackoverflow.com/jobs, or post vs get request from stackoverflow.com/users'